# Find-Package has no -ScriptSourceLocation parameter

Tags: powershell

Why does `Find-Package` not recognize the `-ScriptSourceLocation` parameter?

```
PS H:\> help Find-Package -Full
NAME
    Find-Package

SYNOPSIS
    Finds software packages in available package sources.


SYNTAX
    Find-Package [[-Name] <String[]>] [-AcceptLicense] [-AllowPrereleaseVersions] [-AllVersions] [-Command <String[]>] [-Credential <PSCredential>]
    [-DscResource <String[]>] [-Filter <String>] [-Force] [-ForceBootstrap] [-IncludeDependencies] [-Includes {Cmdlet | DscResource | Function |
    RoleCapability | Workflow}] [-MaximumVersion <String>] [-MinimumVersion <String>] [-PackageManagementProvider <String>] [-ProviderName {Bootstrap |
    NuGet | PowerShellGet}] [-Proxy <Uri>] [-ProxyCredential <PSCredential>] [-PublishLocation <String>] [-RequiredVersion <String>] [-RoleCapability
    <String[]>] [-ScriptPublishLocation <String>] ***[-ScriptSourceLocation <String>]*** [-Source <String[]>] [-Tag <String[]>] [-Type {Module | Script | All}]
    [<CommonParameters>]
```

Howerver, an exception is produced if it is used.

```
PS H:\> Find-Package -ProviderName 'NuGet' -ScriptSourceLocation 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/items/psscript'
Find-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ScriptSourceLocation'.
At line:1 char:36
+ Find-Package -ProviderName 'NuGet' -ScriptSourceLocation 'https://www ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Find-Package], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.FindPackage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're seeing here is a bug, either with `Find-Package` or it could be some quirk/bug with named parameter sets. I would report this at the [Powershell Core issue page](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues) as it looks like it's still an issue with the current version of PowerShell 6. Further testing shows that if you don't specify the `-ProviderName`, the parameter works fine and is recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply the `ScriptSourceLocation` parameter for `NuGet` provider. Consider the following script:

```
$FindPackage_Cmdlet=Get-Command Find-Package
$FindPackage_Cmdlet.ParameterSets.Count                    ## 2
$FindPackage_Cmdlet.DefaultParameterSet                    ## $Null (not defined)
$FindPackage_Cmdlet.ParameterSets | ForEach-Object {
    $aux = $_.Parameters.Name

    $_.Name, ( 'ScriptSourceLocation' -in $aux ) -join ' '  ## NuGet False
                                                            ## PowerShellGet True

    $aux -join ' -'                                         ## (parameters)
}
```

On the other side, the `ScriptSourceLocation` parameter works for `PowerShellGet` provider:

```
(Find-Package -ProviderName 'PowerShellGet' -ScriptSourceLocation 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/items/psscript').Count
```

> ```
> 4956
> ```

### Update

**1.** Please note that your excerpt from `Get-Help Find-Package` seems to be incomplete. Unfortunately, both syntax patterns rely on `[-ProviderName {NuGet | Bootstrap | PowerShellGet}]`:

**`SYNTAX`**

```
Find-Package [[-Name] <string[]>] [-IncludeDependencies] [-AllVersions] [-Source <string[]>] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-Proxy <uri>] [-ProxyCredential <pscredential>] [-RequiredVersion <string>] [-MinimumVersion <string>] [-MaximumVersion <string>] [-Force] [-ForceBootstrap] 
     [-ProviderName {NuGet | Bootstrap | PowerShellGet}] [-ConfigFile <string>] [-SkipValidate] [-Headers <string[]>] [-FilterOnTag <string[]>] [-Contains <string>] [-AllowPrereleaseVersions] [<CommonParameters>]

Find-Package [[-Name] <string[]>] [-IncludeDependencies] [-AllVersions] [-Source <string[]>] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-Proxy <uri>] [-ProxyCredential <pscredential>] [-RequiredVersion <string>] [-MinimumVersion <string>] [-MaximumVersion <string>][-Force] [-ForceBootstrap]
     [-ProviderName {NuGet | Bootstrap | PowerShellGet}] [-AllowPrereleaseVersions] [-PackageManagementProvider <string>] [-PublishLocation <string>] [-ScriptSourceLocation <string>] [-ScriptPublishLocation <string>] [-Type {Module | Script | All}] [-Filter <string>] [-Tag <string[]>] [-Includes {DscResource | Cmdlet | Function | Workflow | RoleCapability}] [-DscResource <string[]>] [-RoleCapability <string[]>] [-Command <string[]>] [-AcceptLicense] [<CommonParameters>]
```

**2.** Tested using built-in intellisense (*Visual Studio*, *PowerShell-ISE*, *PowerShell 6.2*, *Windows PowerShell 5.1*):

ProviderName {**Bootstrap** | **NuGet**}

```
PS D:\PShell> Find-Package -ProviderName Bootstrap -Source
IncludeDependencies      Force                    ErrorAction
AllVersions              ForceBootstrap           WarningAction
Source                   ConfigFile               InformationAction
Credential               SkipValidate             ErrorVariable
Proxy                    Headers                  WarningVariable
ProxyCredential          FilterOnTag              InformationVariable
Name                     Contains                 OutVariable
RequiredVersion          AllowPrereleaseVersions  OutBuffer
MinimumVersion           Verbose                  PipelineVariable
MaximumVersion           Debug

[string[]] Source
```

ProviderName **PowerShellGet**

```
PS D:\PShell> Find-Package -ProviderName PowerShellGet -ScriptSourceLocation
IncludeDependencies        PackageManagementProvider  AcceptLicense
AllVersions                PublishLocation            Verbose
Source                     ScriptSourceLocation       Debug
Credential                 ScriptPublishLocation      ErrorAction
Proxy                      Type                       WarningAction
ProxyCredential            Filter                     InformationAction
Name                       Tag                        ErrorVariable
RequiredVersion            Includes                   WarningVariable
MinimumVersion             DscResource                InformationVariable
MaximumVersion             RoleCapability             OutVariable
Force                      AllowPrereleaseVersions    OutBuffer
ForceBootstrap             Command                    PipelineVariable

[string] ScriptSourceLocation
```

**3.** The intellisense shows even **four different syntax patterns** in PowerShell **5.1**:

```
                         ↓ activate intellisense here pressing Ctrl+Space
PS D:\PShell> Get-Package
Get-Package          Get-PackageProvider  Get-PackageSource

Get-Package [[-Name] <string[]>] [-RequiredVersion <string>] [-MinimumVersion <string>] [-MaximumVersion <string>] [-AllVersions] [-Force] [-ForceBootstrap] [-ProviderName <string[]>] [-Destination <string>] [-ExcludeVersion] [-Scope <string>] [-SkipDependencies] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Package [[-Name] <string[]>] [-RequiredVersion <string>] [-MinimumVersion <string>] [-MaximumVersion <string>] [-AllVersions] [-Force] [-ForceBootstrap] [-ProviderName <string[]>] [-Scope <string>] [-PackageManagementProvider <string>] [-Type <string>] [-AllowClobber] [-SkipPublisherCheck] [-InstallUpdate] [-NoPathUpdate] [-AllowPrereleaseVersions] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Package [[-Name] <string[]>] [-RequiredVersion <string>] [-MinimumVersion <string>] [-MaximumVersion <string>] [-AllVersions] [-Force] [-ForceBootstrap] [-ProviderName <string[]>] [-AdditionalArguments <string[]>] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Package [[-Name] <string[]>] [-RequiredVersion <string>] [-MinimumVersion <string>] [-MaximumVersion <string>] [-AllVersions] [-Force] [-ForceBootstrap] [-ProviderName <string[]>] [-IncludeWindowsInstaller] [-IncludeSystemComponent] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: I would still say this is probably a bug, because the error states the parameter can't be found, not that it's incompatible with the NuGet provider. But, it makes sense that the parameter  can't be used in this context.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I agree that it's a bug because there **isn't defined `DefaultParameterSet`** _although_ there are more parameter sets…

Comment: Can you bind the same parameters but with different allowed values across parameter sets?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I don't understand although I suspect that  coincidence (congruity) of _provider name_ and  _parameter set name_ isn't intentional. However, answer updated.