# PowerShell Gallery vs NuGet Gallery vs MSI vs Snap-Ins

Tags: powershell, module, nuget

I'm quite confused at the differences here and would appreciate some clarification.

What I think is that in PowerShell 1.0, there were Modules (commands written in PowerShell) and Snap-Ins (a dynamic link library that implements cmdlets and providers). However, the lines became blurred as Modules can contain DLLs that the Cmdlets and Functions in the module can call, so eventually Snap-Ins are now effectively redundant.

Then came NuGet packages, which seems to be some kind of package deployment system (build by Microsoft??). This is not PowerShell specific in the way that the PowerShell Gallery is, and NuGet packages can deploy any kind of functionality to a Windows system. Is it correct to think of NuGet as the successor of MSI as a package deployment method?

So, we have PowerShell Gallery (only for PowerShell modules) and NuGet (for anything, but also contains PowerShell *packages*). What is a Package and how is it defined differently from a Module in the context of PowerShell?

Then, I notice that PowerShell have `*-Package` and `*-Module` Cmdlets, so you can run:

```
find-module *7zip*
find-package *7zip*
```

The same four items are returned here, but where are these Cmdlets pointing? If you run `install-module` is the Module installed from the PowerShell Gallery, and if you run `install-package` is an equivalent package (that is not a Module, but a package, whatever that is!) installed from NuGet?

Any clarification on the above would be greatly appreciated as I'm finding it hard to find clear definitions of what all of these things are and how they interact with each other (and indeed, what is the best way for me to approach installing them and upkeep)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59472531/3439404 and [Install-Package vs Install-Module](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/install-package-vs-install-module/).

Comment: Don't forget Chocolatey...

Comment: Install-Package requires you to be an admin but anyone can install a module in their own user scope as a plain user.